# How to mock `angular.element`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

In a service I have the following code snippet

```
angular.element('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: this.parentHeight + ... - ...
    }, 500);
```

In my unit test I want to check if the correct values are given to the `animate` function. But how can I mock or spy this `animate` function ? I can think of something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.element = () => {
        return { animate: (options) => { .. }
    }
});
```

or better (but not working)

```
  spyOn(angular.element('html, body'), 'animate');
```

Is there a better (angular) way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```js
var element = {
  animate: null,
  parentHeight: 100
};
spyOn(angular, 'element').andReturn(element);
spyOn(element, 'animate');

// Your test code goes here

expect(angular.element).toHaveBeenCalledWith('html, body');
expect(element.animate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
      scrollTop: 100
    }, 500);
```

Comment: This will work but you don't test here anything! You test your own mock (animate). and one more thing mostly it is not needed to test actual parameters like 100 and 500

Comment: @user2978188 do you have an alternative to test this? Btw, I do feel that whatever you mean by 'actual' parameters need to be tested as well.  All parameters should be.